# find the possible flights going from one airport to another with at most one intermediate airport stoppage in aggregate framework mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

How to find all possible flights going from 'BAN' to 'CHD' with at most one intermediate airport stoppage?

I basically want to get array of array having either one object(direct flight ) or two object(connected flight with one intermediate airport stoppage)

DATA SET

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc92425f356c05bdafe724a"),
    "to" : "CHD",
    "from" : "BAN"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc92425f356c05bdafe724b"),
    "to" : "CHD",
    "from" : "DEL"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc92425f356c05bdafe724d"),
    "to" : "DEL",
    "from" : "BAN"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc92425f356c05bdafe724e"),
    "to" : "CHD",
    "from" : "CHN"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc9245af356c05bdafe7251"),
    "to" : "BAN",
    "from" : "CHD"
}

OUTPUT REQUIRED

[ 
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc92425f356c05bdafe724a"),
    "to" : "CHD",
    "from" : "BAN"
}],
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc92425f356c05bdafe724b"),
    "to" : "CHD",
    "from" : "DEL"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc92425f356c05bdafe724d"),
    "to" : "DEL",
    "from" : "BAN"
}]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is enough, but feel free to test or mark any error:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
  "$graphLookup": {
    "from": "collection",
    "startWith": "$to",
    "connectFromField": "to",
    "connectToField": "from",
    "as": "flights",
    "maxDepth": 0,
    "restrictSearchWithMatch": { $or: [ { from: "BAN" }, { to: "CHD" } ] }
}},
  { $match: { from: "BAN" } }
])
```

### [Live](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0hrSnWTqZAk)

---

**The Idea** is, that we need:

```
                      A ---> Anywhere
                     
                     Anywhere ---> B
```

Always holding that "Anywhere", is the same place.

1. We take a document, if **neither** to is B or from is A, we discard
2. If Either to is B or from is A, then we look for exact match between to:anywhere and from:anywhere
3. We need to remove this paths: B-->anywhere; Anywhere-->A (the inverse path) which is done with a `$match`

If this is slow, it'd be worth a try to index the "from" fields, like so:

```
db.nameOfDB.createIndex({from:1})
```